# Why does Netbeans show "superclass access check failed" when running a project?

Tags: java, netbeans

I started coding last week using Java and Netbeans, i cant run anything, and the system isnt showing my errors, i got this message at the bottom.

this is the error that came up in the bottom right notifications

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.netbeans.lib.nbjavac.services.CancelAbort (in unnamed module @0x2830c0e8) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.util.Abort (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.util to unnamed module @0x2830c0e8
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader.doLoadClass(JarClassLoader.java:287)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.selfLoadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:246)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.doFindClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:174)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParserFactory.createPrivateParser(JavacParserFactory.java:79)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.JavaSource$JavaSourceAccessorImpl.createCompilationController(JavaSource.java:739)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.JavaSourceUtilImpl.getModuleInfoHandle(JavaSourceUtilImpl.java:271)
at
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You need to be more descriptive in describing how the error occured. Did it happen when you opened Netbeans? Did it happen when you attempted to compile your codes? Did it happen when you hit button A? etc etc

Comment: Which version of Java, and which version of Netbeans?

Comment: It looks like a problem with your Netbeans installation.  Maybe you are using a new version of Java with an old version of Netbeans?

Comment: i solved the problem, i was using a version of NetBeans that didn't support JDK 16, so I deleted this version of netbeans and downloaded a different version. Thanks for the help guys